# Searching by related model field

Tags: search, model, yii, relation

I know there are plenty of topics on this but I searched&tried so many and it is still not working.

I have tables: Team and Worker. Any worker can be assigned to a Team. So at the Workers Manager I want to search Workers also by Team name.

I got the column etc. but when I type part of team name - search starts but the written text dissappears and search doesn't care about the field. I checked the AJAX call with Firebug and there is a field called teamName (I added public field to my Worker model class). But when I print_r criteria in my search method - there is no condition.
How is that possible? How can I perform the searching by related field?

EDIT (my serach() method):

```
public function dsearch()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('idWorker',$this->idWorker);
    $criteria->compare('idLeaderType',$this->idLeaderType);
    $criteria->compare('t.idTeam',$this->idTeam);
    $criteria->compare('idVoip',$this->idVoip);
    $criteria->compare('workLogin',$this->workLogin,true);
    $criteria->compare('workPass',$this->workPass,true);
    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
    $criteria->compare('surname',$this->surname,true);
    $criteria->compare('madeCalls',$this->madeCalls);
    $criteria->compare('deleted',$this->deleted);
    $criteria->compare('liveChanges',$this->liveChanges);
    $criteria->compare('confirmer',$this->confirmer);
    $criteria->compare('oldWorkerNum',$this->oldWorkerNum);
    $criteria->compare('idDepart',$this->idDepart);
    $criteria->compare('Team.name', $this->teamName, true);
    $criteria->with=array('Team');
    $criteria->together = true;

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Have you worked through this tutorial: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/

Comment: have you set the `teamName` attribute as safe in your model rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found usefull extension to do that: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/relatedsearchbehavior/

I couldnt get it to work somehow. I downloaded new version and now its fine.
It works pretty well. Thanks for your time though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mergeWith: Hope it works.

```
 if($merge!==null){
            $criteria->mergeWith($merge);
            }
```

Reference:http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#mergeWith-detail